# Why is this array bugging when I declare a matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

That's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int linhas=0, col=0, num=0, i=0, pos1[100];
    int pos[100];
    scanf("%d %d %d", &linhas, &col, &num);

    int matriz[linhas][col];

    for(i=0; i<num;i++){
       scanf(" %c%d", &pos[i], &pos1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        pos[i] -= 97;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's quite simple, I declared 2 arrays, one to store the value of a char(**pos[]**), and the other to store integer values(**pos1[]**), and it works:D.

The thing is, if I declare a matrix ex: **matrix[linhas][col]**, my code **does not** really store the values of a char, and if I take it off, it starts to store normally, also, it does not matter whether if I declare the matrix right after getting the rows and colums (linhas and col) or if I declare it at the end of the code. I don't know what the problem is, and I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Please include the actual code that's causing you problems and explain what the problems are (e.g. compiler errors, segfault at runtime, doesn't do what I expected etc.).

Comment: `pos` is an array of `int`, not an array of `char`

Comment: `%c` tells `scanf` to expect the address of a `char` not of an `int`. What is the `pos[i] -= 97;` for? Is that my house number or did you mean `'a'`?

Comment: @jarmod done, I just declared a matrix

Comment: Here's your hint: `../main.c:13:17: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @WeatherVane :/ I want the decimal value of a char, then I take 97 of it,

Comment: My point was: if you intended to subtract the numeric value of the letter **a** then subtract `'a'` not some magic number -  then everyone will know the intention.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, thanks for the hint:)

Comment: Not to mention that `pos[i] -= 97` (or 'a') will yield a negative value if an uppercase letter is input.

Comment: @jarmod it does not matter in this case because It's only going to work if it's not uppercase

Comment: Yes, it may be overkill, but my suggestion is that you get into the habit asap of validating your inputs and defensively programming because it will benefit you longer term. You will detect, and fix, bugs much more quickly and your code will be more reliable.

Comment: @jarmod thank you so much for the hint, I really appreacite:D I'll start doing that for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int pos[100];
    scanf("%d %d %d", &linhas, &col, &num);

    int matriz[linhas][col];

    for(i=0; i<num;i++){
       scanf(" %c%d", &pos[i], &pos1[i]);
    }
```

The `%c` format specifier will read in a character, but it requires the address of a character to read it into. You pass it the address of an int.

The simplest fix is to change `pos` to `char pos[100];`. Another possible fix is this:

```
    for(i=0; i<num;i++){
       char c;
       scanf(" %c%d", &c, &pos1[i]);
       pos[i] = c;
    }
```